# Sequential variables with for loop matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, variables

I have a 42 variables of same length and in sequence

e.g. `d_reshaped1` to `d_reshaped42`.

Each variable has 3 rows with 42 elements. I would like to combine all the first rows in each of the 42 variables to a single 42 by 42 matrix but my dynamic programming skills in Matlab are miserable.

Can someone assist?

Comment: Please consider seriously to define a cell array of size 42, or better yet a 3D array of size 3x42x42 to accomodate all your variables. That will make life easier :-)

Comment: It will but my question is  how do i assign the variables into the 3D cell array in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have those variables, you need to use [`eval`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/eval.html), which is generally [not advised](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html#bs7kmd5):

```
result = NaN(42,42);
for k = 1:42
    eval(['result(k,:) = d_reshape' num2str(k) '(1,:)'])
end
```

You should consider using a higher-order structure to store all those variables together, such as a cell array or a 3D array.

Comment: Thanks very much. Not recommended but I really need to get past this problem ASAP.